# Bash Script - initiate remote X redirected application

Tags: bash, shell-script

Perhaps I am using the wrong keywords to find an answer to this requirement.

I have a GUI installed on a remote linux system that use remote connecting into it and initiating the application with X redirection, like this:

```
ssh -Y user.known@aServer.lan
cd /home/user.known/TheAppDir/
sh ./ApplicationCommand
```

with the above I have the GUI displayed on my local linux from the **aServer**

My question is - how can I write a bash on my local linux that would initiate the process above in one go?
Ideally, I want to run a bash script like:

```
aServer.ApplicationCommand
```

And I have the GUI running locally as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the file `aServer.ApplicationCommand` (don't forget the chmod +x to make it executable) and place in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -Y user.known@aServer.lan "cd /home/user.known/TheAppDir/ ; sh ./ApplicationCommand"
```

This should work. You will still be prompted for a password unless you have ssh keys configured.

**Explanation**

SSH can be used strictly to run a command rather than return a session by placing the command after the SSH command. Essentially when doing this it opens a session, runs the provided command and then closes it.

Because you want multiple commands to be executed we simply place a semi-colon between to separate them and enclose in quotations so it remains an argument to the SSH command.

**BONUS**

Rename the script to `aServer` and change the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -Y user.known@aServer.lan "cd /home/user.known/TheAppDir/ ; sh ./$1"
```

and call it using `aServer ApplicationCommand`, the advantage to this is if you have multiple scripts in `TheAppDir` that you want to call you just change the argument.

I think you can even still capture `$?` to see if the script executed properly and create an error message if the file was not found, but you'd have to test that.

Comment: Thanks Dave, it did not work as you suggested. Is there some details that you can think of which may result in this failure?

Comment: I would rather use `ssh -Y user.known@aServer.lan "cd /home/user.known/TheAppDir/ ; sh ./ApplicationCommand"` or else `sh ./ApplicationCommand` will be executer locally.

Comment: It has worked fine.
**THANKS** Dave ! 

I have a **';'** just after connecting to the server when I tried a similar approach - the correct is to have the first command just after the server login.

Comment: @Archemar good catch, edited

Comment: @NicolasDiogo I also added an option that would allow you to run any script in `theAppDir`